# Encontrar de donde proviene la línea de un id dentro de un bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Mucho tiempo e tenido este problema al dar forma a un sistema landing page o herramienta con Bootstrap

Cuando quiero modificar un select traído por un id de un js 
como por ejemplo este :

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
```

Que contiene el select y el search de mi tabla a por ejemplo cambiar "entréis" a "entradas" inspecciono el elemento para poder identificar donde se encuentra su estilo, pero en este caso aparece como si estuviese dentro de mi html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la plantilla que trato de usar tiene cientos de documentos y estos se llaman a otros. como puedo identificar/buscar una línea en especifico para poder encontrar su documento y modificar ?
,alguna intrucion estilo find file by id existira?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas usando Datatable, toma te paso la configuracion que yo uso para cambiar eso, te copio todo el script lo que necesitas configurar es la parte de lenguaje para que te salga en español por ejemplo, ahi tenes muchas configuraciones adicionales, si te sirve alguna bienvenido sea.
Esto lo meto es un script y lo llamo desde la pagina donde lo voy a usar, la linea que modifica lo de show entrys es la que dice "sLengthMenu":"Mostrar *MENU* registros"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  $('#mytable').DataTable(
  {
  responsive: false,
  dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
  fixedColumns: true,
  fixedHeader: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  bSort: true,
  autoWidth: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  lengthMenu: [[5,25, 50, -1], [5,25, 50, "All"]],
  info: true,
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      title: dato,
      className: 'btn',
      text: "Excel",
      exportOptions: {
        columns: ":not(.no-exportar)"
      }
  },
  {
    extend: 'csvHtml5',
    title: dato,
    className: 'btn',
    text: "Csv",
    exportOptions: {
      columns: ":not(.no-exportar)"
    }
},
    {
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      title: dato,
      className: 'btn',
      text: "Pdf",
      exportOptions: {
        columns: ":not(.no-exportar)"
      },
       customize: function ( doc ) {
                doc.content.splice( 1, 0, {
                    margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 12 ],
                    alignment: 'center',
                } );
            }
    },
{
  extend: 'print',
  title: dato,
  className: 'btn',
  text: "Imprimir",
  exportOptions: {
    columns: ":not(.no-exportar)"
  }
 },
 {
extend: 'copy',
title: dato,
className: 'btn',
text: "Copiar",
exportOptions: {
  columns: ":not(.no-exportar)"
}
}
  ],
    language: {
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                          "sFirst":    "Primero",
                          "sLast":     "Último",
                          "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                          "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                        },
            "oAria":    {
                        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                        },
            "decimal": ",",
            "thousands": "."
            }
  });
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias!, la verdad es que me suena bien pero no encuentro el documento a modificaren ningun lado y en realidad esa es mi duda que siempre e tenido problemas para encontrarde donde proviene cada elemento. aqui quiero cambiar a español algunos textos y agregar un parametro de "mostrar 1000" resultados pero nunca encuentro donde cambiar esa parte y queria ver como le hacen para identidficar la rocedencia de un id como en id="datatable-buttons"

Comment: A no habia leido bien voy en el colectivo jajaja, mira ese datatable es asi porque es un plugin es mas facil configurar un archivo final, eso que te pase vos creas un archivo table.js por ejemplo y lo llamas en el html como un scrip, dsp solo tu tabal tiene que tener el mismo id que se llama al comienzo del script en este caso  mytable: $('#mytable').DataTable. Dsp lo otro es con JQUERY llamar al id que necesites pero yo estuve una semana y me ayudaron aca con esa solucion que te pase, no encontraba los datos hasta que configure el lenguaje

Comment: Eso que decis de mostrar 1000 por ejemplo se configura en este linea: lengthMenu: [[5,25, 50, -1], [5,25, 50, "All"]], Yo ahi muestro 5, 25, 50 o todos segun elijas en el select, si queres mostrar 1000 solo lo agregas lengthMenu: [[5,25, 50, 1000, -1], [5,25, 50, 1000, "All"]]

Comment: gracias, pero es decir que es imposible localizar la fuente de alguna linea en mi documento?no es solo por mi Datatable es algo que siempre me a causado problemas encontrar la procedencia de alguna linea